# Values are not ascending correctly, QGIS

Tags: qgis

The values are not ascending correctly, why would it jump from 4 to 39 while all the values in between are also present. [image]

Comment: Your field is formatted as a text field. QGIS orders your data from the first letter (ie number) not the whole number. Go to the field calculator and calculate a new field using to_real("text_field_name)

Comment: Or if you don't want to add a new field, just simply add to_real in the panel you show above (in front of the field name value).